# Using Attribute Table in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

Can the attribute table of a shape layer be modified as a dynamic table, establishing a list of options and making the work easier?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you:

1. right-click a layer and choose "Properties..."
2. then go to the "Attributes form" tab
3. you can edit the properties for each field. E.g. if you want to define a list of options for a text field, you:

   1. select the field in the list
   2. under "Widget type" you choose "Value Map"
   3. in the list you can now specify all possible options.

   [image]

If you open the attribute table and enable editing, a list with options will be shown for the field you configured this for.